# Using gdb gives error "Cannot insert breakpoint 1." "Cannot access memory at address 0x8001779"

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb, breakpoints

I am working on a project in C, and I am running gdb for the first time, and I come into this problem when I try to set a breakpoint and it gives this error.

COMMAND:

```
Reading symbols from ./traffic...
(gdb) break game.c:112
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1779: file game.c, line 112.
(gdb) x 0x1779
0x1779 <controls+466>:  0x90458b48
(gdb) run game_1.txt
```

ERROR:

```
Starting program: /mnt/c/Users/P750/uni/c/assignment2/traffic game_1.txt
warning: opening /proc/PID/mem file for lwp 230.230 failed: No such file or directory (2)
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x8001779
```

I've searched around and tried to copy and paste these lines from the internet

```
stat /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
cat /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

and it still doesn't work. I am not too sure what the above does though.

I've also tried to update my gdb, but in doing so I received a lot of errors while running the 'make' command.

Comment: Are you perhaps inside a WSL environment? If so it doesn't seem to have the `/proc/XX/mem` file, which is apparently needed by GDB.

Comment: After a quick search, it seems to be [a known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8516).

Comment: yes I'm using wsl (Ubuntu-22.04)

Comment: I will try and look through that link

Comment: By the way, the search I had was simply `opening /proc/PID/mem file for lwp failed`. Just putting an error message into your favorite search engine could save you a lot of time.

Comment: Easiest fix may be to install an Ubuntu 20.04 WSL package, if the Windows Store still offers it. It comes with an older GDB (9.1) that will work in the absence of /proc/pid/mem. Its EOL is still a year and a half away. Be sure to run `sudo apt update;sudo apt dist-upgrade` to install all the security updates.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try that out